# Cannot read property ' ' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an Angular form and want to insert data which taken by angular form sqlServer. When I serve Angular get errors

> "Cannot read property 'UserName' of defined"
> "Cannot read property 'UserSurname' of defined" and all other forms.

here is my users-detail.service.ts ı have  *formData:UsersDetail*

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersDetail } from './users-detail.model';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersDetailService {

  formData:UsersDetail
  
  readonly rootURL = 'https://localhost:51128/api'

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  postPaymentDetail(formData:UsersDetail){
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/Users',formData);
  }
}
```

here is my users-detail.service.ts *UsersDetailClass* which referenced in service *formDataUsersDetail*

```js
    export class UsersDetail {

    UserId :number;
    UserName :string;
    UserSurname :string;
    UserEmail :string;
    UserPassword :string;
    UserTypeId :number;
}
```

I have a shared folder contains those 2 ts.

In appModule.ts i have

```js
import { UsersDetailService } from './shared/users-detail.service';
```

and in app module imports[]

```js
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [UsersDetailService],
```

Here is my users-detail folder. Contains users-detail.component.ts and users-detail.component.html

users-detail.component.ts i have

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UsersDetailService } from 'src/app/shared/users-detail.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-detail',
  templateUrl: './users-detail.component.html',
  styles:[]
})
export class UsersDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:UsersDetailService) {}
```

And finally users-detail.component.html I have

```html
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
  <input type="hidden" name="UserId" [value]="service.formData.UserId">
  <input type="hidden" name="UserTypeId" [value]="service.formData.UserTypeId">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.UserName" 
    class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" required="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <input name="UserSurname" #UserSurname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.UserSurname" 
      class="form-control" placeholder="UserSurname" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="UserEmail" #UserEmal="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.UserEmail" 
        class="form-control" placeholder="UserEmail" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <input name="UserPassword" #UserPassword="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.UserPassword" 
          class="form-control" placeholder="UserPassword" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

when I serve angular I don't get error on compile. I get error on Chrome console

> "Cannot read property 'UserName' of defined".

Can't find the problem. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you trying to load data from your servers to fill in your template form? Or are you trying to save data and send it to your servers?

Comment: @wentjun i m trying to save data and send it to servers

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. You cannot directly set a reference to your service on your view template/component.html.

On your component.html, you just need to remove the prefix `service.` from the `ngModel` and `value` attributes from ALL inputs, since formData is the property that is defined on your components.

```
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" [value]="formData?.UserId">
<input type="hidden" name="UserTypeId" [value]="formData?.UserTypeId">

<div class="form-group">
  <input name="UserName" [(ngModel)]="formData?.UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" required="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input name="UserSurname" [(ngModel)]="formData?.UserSurname" class="form-control" placeholder="UserSurname" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input name="UserEmail" [(ngModel)]="formData?.UserEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="UserEmail" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input name="UserPassword" [(ngModel)]="formData?.UserPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="UserPassword" required>
</div>
```

On your user-detail.component.ts, what you can do is to initialise the formData property with an empty object, or an object with the following properties set with a default value (it can be an empty string, or anything that your business logic requires). Since you already have the formData property defined, that actually stores all the data from your forms thanks to [2-way data binding](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

```
export class UsersDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  formData: UsersDetail = undefined;

  constructor(private service:UsersDetailService) {}

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.formData);
    this.service.postPaymentDetail(this.formData).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }) 
  }

}
```

When then the onSubmit() method is fired, you will pass `formData` to the parameters of `postPaymentDetail()` method.

Comment: @Heisenberg oh, I forgot, you need to use the elvis operator to guard it from null values.

Comment: Also, there is no need for all that `#UserPassword="ngModel" ` since you can access your form values from `formData`